# How to ignore base64binary fields when logging SOAP messages?

Tags: java, xml, logging, spring-ws

I am using Spring's `SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor` to log SOAP requests/responses.

Some of the requests/responses contains `base64Binary` fields which takes up a lot of space in the log files and I don't require to log it for my purposes.

Digging into the code of `SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor` I can see the `java.xml.transform.Transformer` used is created like this:

```
Transformer transformer = createTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
return transformer;
```

Are there some properties I can set on the `Transformer` which will prevent it from printing out the contents of the `base64Binary` fields? Or anything else I can configure or override to prevent it from being logged?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about Transformer, however I would think that a Base64 field will have roughly equal numbers of uppercase and lowercase letters.  Normal text will tend to have either many more lowercase or be all uppercase.  You may be able to determine the difference that way.

Also there are punctuation characters that never appear in Base64.  Seeing any one of those will tell you that the field is not Base64.